# Is the ability to do a full balance desirable or necessary with btrfs?

Tags: btrfs, suse

I believe I do not have the *ideal* correct filesystem layout to run btrfs and that what I've got looks more like an ext4 filesystem layout.  There are no subvolumes except for /.snapshots and

Basically, I've got a few hundred machines that look like this:

```
/dev/mapper/system-root     2097152  396120   1230536  25% /
/dev/mapper/system-usr      3670016 1778496   1434560  56% /usr
/dev/mapper/system-boot      524288  128848    202320  39% /boot
/dev/mapper/system-root     2097152  396120   1230536  25% /.snapshots
/dev/mapper/system-root     2097152  396120   1230536  25% /srv
/dev/mapper/system-root     2097152  396120   1230536  25% /root
/dev/mapper/system-opt      2097152  754016    978080  44% /opt
/dev/mapper/system-tmp      1048576    4352    751936   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/system-home    10485760 1312884   8594316  14% /home
/dev/mapper/system-var      8388608 2695188   5342956  34% /var
/dev/mapper/system-splunk   8388608 3648160   4311040  46% /opt/splunk
/dev/mapper/system-zypp     1048576   31236    725500   5% /var/cache/zypp
```

Upgraded to Sles15 - SP3 and ran into a pretty bad bug where some `events_unbound` thread goes and gobbles up all the CPU, *perf* showed me that it was caused by a btrfs maintenance job and digging into it a bit more I found that it was patched in 2021 (but probably not backported into sles15)

All that aside, the workaround for this issue seems to be just to give all the filesystems enough disk so they can each perform a `btrfs balance start --full-balance /path/to/thing`

I'm finding I have to add space to a lot of these volumes in order to do that (even ones that report something like 50% free space).

So, what I want to know is, should I be monitoring to make sure that I am able to do a full balance on each of these filesystems and is there a way, short of actually doing the balance, that I can find a good threshold for the ideal amount of free space on each filesystems so if one gets to a certain percent full (or another meaningful metric) I can whip up some sort of event and remediate it before it starts chewing on my CPU?

Comment: I've found that if I first do 50%, then 75%, then 90% dusage,  etc., then the total space required for a full balance is reduced. YMMV.

Comment: @rick yes, we've found that to be the case.  I think that's why btrfsmaintenance lets you specify "50 75 90"  or whatever works for you. in the config file.   It's way too luck-driven for my tastes!

Comment: I've even found that a "50" after a full will sometimes reduce overall space.